# How to sort lines by length with batch script?

Tags: sorting, batch-file, line

I wanna make script, which in document example.txt sort all lines by length (some line has spaces). The longest line will be first line, the shortest line will be at end of the document. Script can rewrite original document. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is surprisingly easy and fast to accomplish this by writing each line as its own file within a temporary folder. Then use DIR /B /O-S to sort the files (lines) by size, capturing the result with FOR /F and then printing each file (line) with TYPE.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "file=example.txt"
set "tempLoc=sortLinesTemp"

md "%tempLoc%"
set "cnt=0"
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%file%") do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo(!ln!>"%tempLoc%\f!cnt!"
  endlocal
)
(for /f %%F in ('dir /b /o-s "%tempLoc%"') do type "%tempLoc%\%%F")>"%file%.new"
move /y "%file%.new" "%file%" >nul
rd /s /q "%tempLoc%"
type "%file%"
```

This solution will strip empty lines. Empty lines can be preserved with a bit more code.

Also, line lengths are limited to a bit less than 8191 characters. This limitation is inherent to any pure native batch solution.

Comment: Thank you, this script works. In my document aren´t empty lines, so it is ok.

Answer (score 3):

This batch file uses a VBS script to help get the line lengths, and sorts, then rewrites the `input.txt` file into `input.new.txt`

Use the batch like this: `sortline.bat "filename.txt"`

Leading `|` characters in a line will vanish.

```
@echo off
set "file=%temp%\sortline.vbs"
(
 echo. Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
 echo. infile = "%~1"
 echo. Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
 echo. Set f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(infile, ForReading^)
 echo. Do While not f1.AtEndOfStream
 echo. f = f1.readline
 echo. Wscript.echo right(10000+len(f^),4^) ^& "|" ^& f
 echo. loop
 echo. f1.close
)>"%file%"
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%a in (' cscript //nologo "%file%" ^|sort /r ') do echo(%%b)>"%~n1.new.txt"
del "%file%"
```

Comment: Small bug - you should use `echo(%%b` to protect against empty lines or lines containing only spaces. Another limitation - line lengths are limited to ~8191 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the simplest and fastest way to do that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A seqNum=10000, accumLen=0
set "lastLine="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /O "^" example.txt') do (
   if not defined lastLine (
      set "lastLine=%%b"
   ) else (
      set /A "seqNum+=1, thisLen=10000-(%%a-accumLen), accumLen=%%a"
      set "line[!thisLen!!seqNum:~-4!]=!lastLine!"
      set "lastLine=%%b"
   )
)
for %%a in (example.txt) do (
   set /A "seqNum+=1, thisLen=10000-(%%~Za-accumLen)"
   set "line[!thisLen!!seqNum:~-4!]=!lastLine!"
)
(for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set line[') do echo %%b) > sorted.txt
```

This solution strip empty lines and exclamation marks from the file. Both limitations may be fixed, if needed.

Comment: @dbenham: `seqNum` counts from 10001 onward and `!seqNum:~-4!` is my standard way to generate a number 4 digits long with left zeros, that is used to preserve lines with the same length. For example, two lines with length 23: `line[99770001]=...` and `line[99770002]=...`

Comment: Oops- Sorry, I missed the minus sign in the expression, and the line corruption caused me to think that you were missing lines from the output. However, there is no need to pad the seqNum to a constant width. The value is needed to differentiate lines of same length. But the sort order of equal length lines is not important.

Comment: There are two additional limitations. 1) leading : chars are stripped from each line - this can be fixed. 2) Line lengths are limited to ~8175 chars. This cannot be fixed.

Comment: @dbenham: I think this method should be much faster than your method to create one file per line if the input file is large...

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to find the opposite is true. With a small file containing 3183 lines, your code was marginally faster at 5 sec compared to 7.3 sec for mine. But with a larger file containing 13155 lines, my code took 27 sec, but your code took a whopping 77 sec. And my hard drive is fairly slow by today's standards. It certainly isn't a solid state drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [strLen function from this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#Function.strLen).     Also, [here is a download link](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.SortTextWithNumbers) to download sortn.bat , which will give you the hints to get started.   Also, you need to be familiar with the basic compare function:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {             
        if (o1.length()!=o2.length()) {
            return o1.length()-o2.length();
        }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
```

Good luck.